# Get a cell value from datatable with two condition in where clause with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

This is my Table:

[image]

I am trying to get sub_key_value where `key=Trainee` and `aub_key_name=BM`

I have tried:

```
var query = from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
            where r.Field<string>("Key") == "Trainee" 
            where r.Field<string>("Sub_Key_Value") == "BM"
            select r;
```

Here dt is this table and it show "Enumeration yielded no results".
How to get a cell value from DataTable here with multiple conditions?

I would like to know other ways also in which I can accomplish this.

Comment: From looking at your data table you are querying the wrong column, Should be `Sub_Key_Name` and not `Sub_Key_Value`.

Comment: @Magnus i changed that bit still it is "Enumeration yielded no results"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are querying the wrong column. The code should be:

```
var query = from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
                    where r.Field<string>("Key") == "Trainee" 
                    where r.Field<string>("Sub_Key_Name") == "BM"
                    select r;
```

If you only need the `Sub_Key_Value` you should try:

```
var query = from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
                    where r.Field<string>("Key") == "Trainee" 
                    where r.Field<string>("Sub_Key_Name") == "BM"
                    select r.Field<string>("Sub_Key_Value");
```

Comment: Do you get this error here or where you are enumerating the results?
Is it possible the datatable is out of scope or has it been disposed of?

Comment: @Scrobi its strange ,  your query should work well but it did not , i tried in different way and that works dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("key")=="Trainee").Where(y=>y.Field<string>(‌​"Sub_Key_Name")=="BM‌​").Select(z=>z.Field‌​<string>("Sub_Key_Va‌​lue"));

Comment: My guess would be because you are now selecting a string value from the datatable - I have updated my answer that also selects the Sub_Key_Value using the original syntax. Glad you got it working though.

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
                    where r.Field<string>("Key") == "Trainee" 
                    && r.Field<string>("Sub_Key_Value") == "BM"
                    select r;
```

Comment: An explanation would be nice too. I know the solution, but it might be less obvious to OP or future visitors with similar problems.

Comment: still "Enumeration yielded no results"

Comment: Your answer should works but dont know why it is not showing result , This works for me dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("key")=="Trainee").Where(y=>y.Field<string>("Sub_Key_Name")=="BM").Select(z=>z.Field<string>("Sub_Key_Value"));